# ASM - Optimized `for` loop

Tags: c, optimization, assembly, dlx

In homework I received a task to change a C code to ASM of simplified [DLX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLX):

```
a = 0;
for (i = 1; i < 14; i++)
    a = a + c;
A[0] = a;
```

### My solution:

Assuming:

- Value of `a` is in register R1
- Value of `c` is in register R2
- Value of `i` is in register R3
- Value of address of `A` (means `&A`) is in register R4

Then:

```
addi R1 R0 0    // init a = 0
addi R3 R0 1    // init i = 1
slti R5 R3 14   // test (i < 14) ; R5 = 1 if i < 14
beqz R5 3       // branch 3 lines of R5 == 0
add R1 R1 R2    // a = a + c
addi R3 R3 1    // i++
beqz R0 -5      // return up to the condition of the for loop
sw R1 R4 0      // A[0] = 0
```

### Their solution:

Assuming:

- Value of `a` is in register R1
- Value of `i` is in register R2 *(notice the change here)*
- Value of `c` is in register R3 *(notice the change here)*
- Value of address of `A` (means `&A`) is in register R4

Then:

```
addi R1 R0 0    // a = 0
addi R2 R0 1    // i = 1
add R1 R1 R3    // a = a+c
addi R2 R2 1    // i++
slti R5 R2 14   // R5=1 iff i<14
bnez R5 -4      // jump 4 lines up from the next line if
                // R5!=0, that is if i<14
sw R1 R4 0      // store the new value of A[0]=a (R1)
```

---

### Difference:

Their solution is obviously better because that there's 1 less command - my code has an additional conditional branching. Their code is exactly what I wanted to do in the first place, but then I recalled of the `for` loop algorithm:

1. Initialize a variable
2. Check if condition is `True`.
   If `True`: Apply commands within the loop,
   Otherwise: exit the loop.
3. Increment variable
4. return to #2

So their code differs from the for loop algorithm, because that it doesn't check the condition (#2) after the initialization (#1)...
I thought to myself - is this the result of an optimization? 
What level of optimization is this? (IIRC there are 4 levels: O0, O1, O2, O3)
Is it expected to optimize code by default when interpreting a C code?

Comment: `HW`? `DLX`? Which CPU? Ask your tutor. If both codes are correct, the question is OT on SO. This is no CR site.

Comment: @Olaf HW means homework. I know OT is OffTopic, but what is CR?

Comment: @Dor CR means CodeReview, another stackexchange website based on... Code review. But I don't think your question is off-topic, as long as you are not asking for improving, but for explanation.

Comment: code review. And you did not answer the other issues. Please edit your question.

Comment: @Olaf The only other issue is CPU.. but it is not relevant, we were never given data about specific CPUs. Also why should it be relevant? The only important thing is to know the ISA. Having a CPU with specific features seems irrelevant IMHO...

Comment: You missunderstood my point. Just searched for `DLX` now and found it. You forget there are other countries in the world and other fields of application where the DLX Processor is not so well known as you might think, so the term "DLX" is not automatically noticed as **being** the name of the CPU. After all, it is just used at some universities.

Comment: "IRC there are 4 levels: O0, O1, O2, O3" The C standard does not even talk about optimization. The compiler just has to prove the code behaves as for the abstract machine. The number/names of levels and the optimization goal is compiler-specific (or even linker-specific, talking about LTO). If you refer to gcc, you are also wrong. There are at least two more.

Comment: If you want to optimize, you can eliminate the loop completely.

Comment: @Olaf OK don't attack man.. I'm innocent =D.  
Also I think that DLX is the architecture, not the name of a/the CPU. Different CPUs might have a DLX design with additional features...

Comment: 1) I did not attack. 2) Read the WP article about `DLX`, It is a pure hypothetical/educational Processor Architecture; I used the shorter CPU for that. There is no real implementation, so there is no problem using both terms. Point is, it is not clear to eveyone `DLX` actually is the Architecture, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an optimization is activated, your compiler review its assembly code in order to see if there is anything to improve, in particular avoid useless instructions or check.

For instance, in your code, the `for` loop is an initialization, then a classic `while` loop. A classic optimization is to check if a `while` condition can be false at the first entry, and if not, transform it in a `do while` loop.
This is precisely your case. `i < 14` cannot be false if you check it just after an instruction meaning `i = 1`. So it is faster to run:

```
a = 0;
i = 1;
do
{
    a = a + c;
    i++;
} while (i < 14);
A[0] = a;
```

So yes, it is a form of optimization. But when you code directly in assembly language, you are usually expected to do this kind of tricks, because the goal of assembly programming (and mainly learn it) is to make your code as fast as possible, using any possibilities to reduce instruction calls.

This is a result of level O1 optimization on GCC.